# How to merge all columns with the same label after transposing dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, transformation

I have a df that looks like this after 'Transposing' the df:

```
                     1     2                     3            4           5  \
level_1     questionId  type                 value  exportLabel  questionId   
0        participantId    id  -Ll4truw3KbSjVRtXmJy       Viewed    viewTime   

            6                         7            8  
level_1  type                     value  exportLabel  
0        time  2019-07-31T02:41:34.063Z      Started
```

How do I merge the values `level_1` index row if the names match and make them into columns?

The new df should look like this:

```
    questionId       type          value            exportLabel
  0  participantId    id    -Ll4truw3KbSjVRtXmJy         Viewed    
  1  viewTime         time  2019-07-31T02:41:34.063Z    Started
```

I tried `groupby` but the data gets converted back into series and the index becomes the columns, with this code:

```
df = df.groupby(df.loc['level_1'])
```

Comment: it will be helpful if you can post the code to recreate that dataframe(since it is a multiindex)

Comment: @anky_91 are you asking for the very original dataframe?

Comment: No, when posting a multiindexed dataframe sample, it is advisable to post the code to reproduce it rather than copyable data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df (your data).. Generated using below

temp = StringIO("""  
                     1     2                     3            4           5   6          7            8  
level_1     questionId  type                 value  exportLabel  questionId  type      value  exportLabel   
0        participantId    id  -Ll4truw3KbSjVRtXmJy       Viewed    viewTime   time  2019-07-31T02:41:34.063Z      Started  

""")

df = pd.read_csv(temp, sep='\s+')
##df


                     1     2                     3            4           5  \
level_1     questionId  type                 value  exportLabel  questionId   
0        participantId    id  -Ll4truw3KbSjVRtXmJy       Viewed    viewTime   

            6                         7            8  
level_1  type                     value  exportLabel  
0        time  2019-07-31T02:41:34.063Z      Started
```

---

```
df = df.T.groupby('level_1')['0'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))).unstack().T
del df.columns.name
print(df[['questionId','type','value','exportLabel']])
```

---

```
      questionId  type                     value exportLabel
0  participantId    id      -Ll4truw3KbSjVRtXmJy      Viewed
1       viewTime  time  2019-07-31T02:41:34.063Z     Started
```